# Can the US Supreme Court hear an appeal from State Supreme Court w/o a federal question?

Tags: jurisdiction, us-supreme-court, appeal

Is it a matter of choice that the US Supreme Court will reject a case from a State Supreme Court that does not have a federal question or are there binding *jurisdictional* requirements that would prevent them as well? I understand the point about their inability to reinterpret state law already interpreted by state courts.

Answer (score 2):

No, it cannot:

- Federalism allows state courts to have the final word on the interpretation of state laws.
- Article III of the U.S. Constitution imposes a jurisdictional requirement of an actual "case or controversy" on all federal courts.
- Therefore, without the authority to reverse the state court's decision, there is no "controversy" in a case where the interpretation of state law is the deciding question.

**Long answer:** When the state-law interpretation is adequate to justify the state supreme court's decision and is independent of any question of federal law, a SCOTUS decision cannot change the outcome of the case. And if hearing a dispute cannot change its outcome, you have not satisfied Article III's "case or controversy" requirement

The Supreme Court has pretty much always adhered to the view that it has no jurisdiction to review a state court decision that rested on "adequate and independent state grounds," meaning that the state court decision would not change if the meaning of some federal law changed:

> [T]he relations which the State courts sustain to this court are not those of an inferior court of the United States. Congress cannot impose duties upon them, nor invest them with judicial power. They were created by the several States to interpret and give effect to their respective constitutions and laws, and to administer justice according to law. ... Human ingenuity may be challenged to offer a reason why ‘the judgment or decree’ of the State court should be reversed here upon a point having no relation to, or connection with, the question, in the absence of which this court would confessedly have no jurisdiction whatever of the suit.

[*Murdock v. City of Memphis*, 87 U.S. 590, 612–13, (1874)](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/87/590/#636)

For instance, imagine that you live in a state whose constitution provides protections against unreasonable searches and seizures identical to the those in the Fourth Amendment. The police arrest you, and you seek to suppress evidence that you say they took in violation of the state constitution. The state supreme court says the search violated the Fourth Amendment and therefore the state constitution -- suppress the evidence.

The state-law question is not "independent" of the federal question, so if the state court is wrong about what the Fourth Amendment allows, it is also wrong about what state law allows. SCOTUS can hear the case to decide the Fourth Amendment question, which could change the answer to the state law question, change the decision to suppress, and therefore change the outcome of the case.

But imagine the same decision in a state whose constitution provides protection against unreasonable searches and seizures greater than those provided in the Fourth Amendment. The state supreme court might be wrong about what the Fourth Amendment allows, but it can't be wrong about what the state constitution allows (at least not in any way that matters).

What would happen if SCOTUS heard the case? There are two possible outcomes:

- It might decide that Fourth Amendment analysis was correct -- suppress the evidence for violating the Fourth Amendment.
- It might decide that the Fourth Amendment analysis was wrong -- suppress the evidence anyway for violating the state constitution.

If the outcome can't change, there is no case or controversy, which is also a jurisdictional requirement. [*Simon v. E. Kentucky Welfare Rights Org.*, 426 U.S. 26, 37 (1976)](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/426/26/) ("No principle is more fundamental to the judiciary's proper role in our system of government than the constitutional limitation of federal-court jurisdiction to actual cases or controversies.")

So in the end, federalism and jurisdictional limitations would bar the Court from hearing the case.

Comment: Isn't the state supreme court free to interpret the state's 4th amendment differently than how the federal 4th is interpreted by the federal courts, even if the wording is identical?

Comment: @DM It can be interpreted differently, but many states generally interpret their constitutional provisions to provide *exactly* the protection provided by the federal constitution. In those states, "SCOTUS said the 4th Amendment doesn't ban X" is a valid argument that the state constitution doesn't ban X either. If a state court wants to interpret their constitutional provision differently from the way SCOTUS interprets the federal constitution, they'll generally make that explicit. If they didn't do it before SCOTUS heard the case, they could always do it on remand.

Comment: Yep, it is free to do that.

Answer (score -2):

> Can the US Supreme Court hear an appeal from State Supreme Court w/o a
>   federal question?

Yes, it can. But it does so only when they feel like it. By "they" I mean the "Justices" or their staff attorneys on whom they delegate the job.

U.S. Supreme Court Rule 10 has the clause that, although rare, a petition for writ of certiorari can be granted "*when the asserted error consists of erroneous factual findings or the misapplication of a properly stated rule of law*". That premise involves no jurisdictional qualifier or restriction.

Rule 10 highlights its vague and discretionary nature (as opposed to jurisdictional constraints) with language such as "*although neither controlling nor fully measuring the Court's discretion*".

> I understand the point about their inability to reinterpret state law
>   already interpreted by state courts.

I would not be sure about that inability. First, the clause of *Equal Protection* of the Fourteenth Amendment of the U.S. constitution is present in many (if not all) the states. Thus, where state courts' interpretation of state legislation depends on *who* the parties are, there is a compelling need for SCOTUS's exercise of its supervisory power.

And second, a state court can (and does) switch its interpretation of state laws. The inconsistencies that that switching triggers with respect to federal case law reinforces the need for the SCOTUS to review the matter.

One example is Michigan [MCL 408.481(1)](http://www.legislature.mi.gov/(S(nxjiwbkpahibgetl2fvhkhl2))/mileg.aspx?page=getObject&objectName=mcl-408-481). When federal district court decided [*Stubl v. T.A. Systems, Inc.*, 984 F.Supp. 1075 (1997)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/19972059984fsupp107511953), Michigan case law was that the term "may" in MCL 408.481 was permissive rather than mandatory (the conclusion was that a plaintiff is not required to exhaust administrative remedies prior to filing suit). Federal judge Rosen agreed, and even stated (*Stubl* at 1093) that

> Though the Court understands that in extraordinary circumstances the
>   word "may" is interpreted to mean "shall," the Court finds no such
>   circumstance in this Michigan statute.

Plain English. But three years later, another Michigan appellate panel had a change of mood (or who knows? maybe illegitimate incentives, but let's not speculate) and concluded in [*Cork v. Applebee's of Mich., Inc.*, 239 Mich.App. 311; 608 N.W.2d 62, 65 (2000)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/2000670608nw2d621666) that "may" means *mandatory* in that statute.

That is, in the *Cork* panel's mind, the panels from previous Michigan case law and federal judge Rosen had no idea what they were talking about when analyzing MCL 408.481. The result is that the exact same Michigan statute can mean one thing today and the opposite tomorrow.

This erraticism by Michigan judges should prompt the SCOTUS to remind judges of the distinction between permissive "may" and mandatory "shall", just as it did in [*United States v. Rodgers*, 461 U.S. 677, 706 (1983)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/19831138461us67711110).

On page 37 of my [Petition for Writ of Certiorari](https://www.supremecourt.gov/search.aspx?filename=/docket/docketfiles/html/public/17-1576.html), my arguments compel the SCOTUS to renewedly make that reminder of plain English. But this time the SCOTUS preferred to look the other way and single-handedly denied my petition (some lawyers and maybe law academics here in SE rush to defend the judiciary from my denouncements of it, but this is a clear example of judges' arbitrariness and why I do not partake in the game of praising the "judicial" system).

Comment: This answer is incorrect in many ways. You may want to read more about Article III limitations on jurisdiction, the definition of a "federal question," and the *Erie* Doctrine.

Comment: @bdb484 (1) Not everything must be "incorrect", though ,since your example about the 4th Amendment largely mimics the point I made in my answer hours earlier about the Equal Protection clause of the 14th Amendment. (2) Article III does not deprive the SCOTUS of jurisdiction; instead, it lists types of cases where it invariably has original or appellate jurisdiction. (3) I do not dispute the *Erie* doctrine, but it is irrelevant to the point I made about state court's erraticism in interpreting plain English language of state legislation. That erraticism fails an "adequate state grounds" test.

Comment: @IñakiViggers It seems like you're misinterpreting that last sentence of rule 10. When it says "A petition for a writ of certiorari is rarely granted when the asserted error consists of erroneous factual findings or the misapplication of a properly stated rule of law", it's merely stating that such petitions are unlikely to be granted; it's not providing a new category of petitions that can be granted regardless of jurisdictional issues.

Comment: And, of course, if a party is pleading a violation of the equal protection clause of the 14th Amendment, then there *is* a federal question, even if we're dealing with a state law.

Comment: @IñakiViggers (1) The Fourth Amendment and Equal Protection analyses are completely different. Yours creates a federal question; mine eliminates one. (2) Article III does deprive SCOTUS of jurisdiction, at least in the absence of a case or controversy. (3) You do, in fact, dispute the *Erie* doctrine: (a) you suggest that SCOTUS may "reinterpret state law already interpreted by state courts"; and (b) you want federal courts to ignore state-court interpretations of MCL 408.481. That's exactly what *Erie* forbids. As I said, you may want to do some more reading before more writing.

Comment: @DM I agree with your comments, but my point is that Rule 10 could have explicitly excluded types of cases. Instead it says that such petitions are rarely granted, and the rule's emphasis is on the SCOTUS's unconstrained discretion on whether or not to grant petitions.

Comment: @IñakiViggers I agree that it's kind of weird to call something a "rule" when it is "neither controlling nor fully measuring the Court's discretion".

Comment: @bdb484 You evade my point. Where a state court interprets state law in a way and it later re-interprets the same statute but now in the opposite way, each time leading to contradictory outcomes, it inherently incurs a violation of the Equal Protection clause because it results in a varying application of the law. The violation of Equal Protection is what the SCOTUS criticized in *Erie R. Co. v. Tompkins*, 304 U.S. 64, 74-75. State court's re-interpretations are just a pretext/mechanism for what *Erie* at 75 would call "*prevent[ing] uniformity in the administration of the law of the State*".

Comment: I regret to inform you that you continue to be incorrect. There has been plenty of ink spilled on *Erie*, so I'm going to leave it to you to do the reading.

Comment: @bdb484 Thank you. But in case you have not noticed, the citations in my previous comment on "*equal application of the law*" as the SCOTUS expressed its alleged concern about "*uniformity in the administration of the law of the State*" are taken from the [*Erie* opinion](https://www.leagle.com/decision/1938368304us641363) itself, which is a more direct source than "ink spilled on *Erie*".

Comment: I had, but cherry-picking quotes is the easy part. I'm suggesting that deeper inquiry might help you to apply the rule properly.

Comment: @bdb484 It is not cherry-picking; it led to the 2nd of the 4 holdings in *Erie*. You are just pretending that the concern therein for Equal Protection of state law is *obiter dictum* at most. You will find no sign in the *Erie* decision that its intent was to entitle state courts to be erratic so they can obliterate plain statutory language of state legislation. This might exemplify the remark in *Erie at 87* that "*It is hard to foresee the consequences of the radical change so made*". *Erie* did not address that. This is why I told you in my first reply that *Erie* is irrelevant to my point.

Comment: You're continuing to scrounge for useful language instead of just applying the doctrine. Both state and federal courts behaved as expected under *Erie* in your example. I suspect you are having trouble applying the rule because of your personal stake in it. That is normal, but it doesn't make you right.

Comment: @bdb484 I am not "scrounging for useful language", as you crave to portray. I am pointing to dysfunctional ramifications (doctrinal, if you wish) and inconsistencies that the judiciary refuses to address. Theoretical nuances of federalism aside, not all of us applaud the judges' nonsensical suppression of the plain language found in state legislation.

Comment: Complaining about judges is valid, but it seems pretty far from being helpful to anyone with questions about how the law actually works.

Comment: @bdb484 Substantiating judicial inconsistencies is part of explaining how the law actually "works", even if in your mindset the judges' disavowal of the law is a taboo. I prefer not to fool people with the false notion that the judiciary is always willing to follow the tenets of justice, enacted statutes, or oftentimes even the case law of their own jurisdiction.

Comment: I totally get that and agree that it's an important part of providing legal advice. I'm just saying that even if that's what you're doing here, you're doing it incorrectly.